# Packer - 1st: How to create a file in the machine. 2nd: Export machine to ova file

Tags: virtualbox, packer

I use Packer to create a template file which is deployed via API to our provider.

The template is built from CentOS 7.4 minimal ISO file, using a kickstart anaconda-ks.cfg.

In that kickstart file I'm configuring what packages to install in my template and in the post-config part of the kickstart file I run different `bash` commands to configure it. On this post-config I also run a few `cat > /path/file.sh <<EOF` to put some files on disk.

1st.

One of the files is quite large and although I've tried with splitting it in pieces, one last piece freeze the template creation. I can see nothing wrong in my code. Seems to me like the last `cat >> /path/file.sh <<EOF` just freezes Packer job.

The question is if there is any method like in `Terraform` to use a template file somewhere in the Packer directory structure that will be used as a source to create that `/path/file.sh` file in my template.

2nd.

When the template is finished I need to export it to an `.ova` file, because my provider does not accept any other file type.

As in my json file I'm using builder type `virtualbox-iso` and post-processors type `vagrant`, I'm wondering how can I do the last part - to export to ova.

My first thought was to use `ovftool`, but as I'm new to packer I do not know how to insert that in my Packer code.

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the [file provisioner](https://packer.io/docs/provisioners/file.html)
2. Set `"format": "ova"` in your template and remove the `vagrant` post-processor unless you need a vagrant box too. *) See [virtualbox-iso: format](https://packer.io/docs/builders/virtualbox-iso.html#format)

*) If you really need that you should run a *shell-local* post-provisioner in parallel with the vagrant one that converts the ovf to ova instead of setting format, since most likely the vagrant box must contain an ovf.

Comment: Thank you. I would give up on vagrant for now.